# Bulleted List with bullet flush left and Hanging Indent

Tags: html, markdown, indentation

I'm looking for the proper way to code a bulleted list, in html or markdown, with the bullet flush left, a tab space after the bullet and a hanging indent directly under the bulleted line. I've tried hacking it together with spaces, and various lists but nothing looks good. Any suggestions?

I'm trying to make it look like this:

This is my list

**∙  Line One**
        *Line Two*

Comment: What do you mean by "a tab space after the bullet"?

Comment: Could you post the code you've tried, and explain what's not working with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is going to require a two-part solution:

1. **Use Markdown to semantically represent a multi-line list item.**

   Depending on whether "Line Two" should be a new paragraph or simply a new line, you can do this with

   ```
   * Line one

   ␣␣␣␣New paragraph
   ```

   or

   ```
   * Line one␣␣
   New line
   ```

   where `␣` represents a space.
2. **Style this list as you wish to see it.** The spacing before and after a bullet is purely aesthetic, and cannot be represented in Markdown.

   CSS styling along the lines of this should do it:

   ```css
   ul {
     /* Make bullet left-flush, value chosen by experimentation */
     padding-left: 10px;
   }

   ul li {
     /* Add padding to list item, which amounts to space between the
        bullet and the text */
     padding-left: 1.5em;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <!-- Generated by Markdown -->
   <ul>
     <li>Line one<br>
       New line</li>
   </ul>
   ```

Comment: Thank you, Chris! Your two-part method is much better than my use of spaces, and it flows perfectly on all devices.

Comment: I can not easily ship a separate css since the files get moved around so needs to be self-contained. Can the css be retained within the same .md file?   For the first approach it does not really work: the two lines are allided into one flowing line

Comment: @WestCoastProjects, Markdown itself has no concept of presentation. It's all about content. However, depending on the particular implementation you are using and ecosystem within which you are operating there might be a better answer.

Comment: @Chris  It seems I had had an inconsistent number of spaces: your answer does work when i am careful about it.

Answer (score 0):

```css
ul {
  /* Make bullet left-flush, value chosen by experimentation */
  padding-left: 10px;
}

ul li {
  /* Add padding to list item, which amounts to space between the
     bullet and the text */
  padding-left: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<!-- Generated by Markdown -->
<ul>
  <li>Line one<br>
    New line</li>
</ul>
```